# image inside PHP File

Tags: php

I tried some other suggestions I found on this site already but they caused some display issues after loading file.

Just wanting to figure out how to add an image and some text to a php file inside an if else statement.

Here's what I'm starting with:

```
{
    if ($is_search) {
        $return = 'No results!';
    } else {
        $return = "hmmm. How do I add an image here?";
    }
}
```

Thanks to anyone who contributes!

Comment: `$return = "<img src=…>";` The if/else has no obvious relevancy to this question.

Comment: That worked. Would you also happen to know how to add a class or ID/Selector to the image so that it can be styled without inline styles being added to the php file?

Comment: Same as always: `<img src='…' class=largylarge>`

Comment: Thanks Mario for your help!